# Запуск программы с DevExpress на другом компьютере

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, devexpress

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой - имеется программа на WPF с использованием DevExpress. Когда запускаю на другом компьютере (даже через exe) и использую, допустим, встроенные средства фильтрации GridControl, то программы вылетает. Такая же проблема и с отображением ChartControl. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делайте логгирование, показывайте стектрейс ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы не перенесли нужные библиотеки DevExpreess вместе с exe.
Смотрите [Assembly Deployment Tool](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AssemblyDeploymentTool/17237/Assembly-Deployment-Tool).

Comment: Я включил в файлах приложения "Обязательно включить" все библиотекиDevExpress. Получается это не то. Я попозже попробую и отвечу если что